# Setting a review policy when creating Mechanical Turk HITs in bulk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I'm using the Java API for Mechanical Turk and I'd like to give a review policy to HITs.

This [blog post](http://mechanicalturk.typepad.com/blog/2012/11/evaluating-performance-with-known-answers.html) mentions that you can provide an answer key to a HIT question and set a [review policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_AssignmentReviewPolicies.html) such that the HIT will be automatically accepted or rejected based on known answers.

- I'm currently using the `createHITs` methods in `com.amazonaws.mturk.service.axis.RequesterService` to create HITs in bulk. Under this set of methods, I can't find a way to provide an answer key, and load the answers in bulk from an input file.
- I've looked into a few more classes (like `HIT` and `RequesterServiceRaw`) for a way to change created HITs and add a policy to them - can't find anything.
- Finally I thought I might be able to provide a review policy through the `HITProperties`, but that doesn't seem doable either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HITReviewPolicies.html). You can set review policies to reach consensus among workers or check workers accuracy against workers responses.